# How to bind match in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have this code:

```
...
import { match, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import * as H from 'history';

interface oneRoute {
    path: string;
    exact?: boolean;
    main: any;
}

interface ITestProps {
    id: string;
}

class Test extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<ITestProps>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>Hallow id:{this.props.match.params.id} -- {JSON.stringify(this.props.match)}</div>
    }
} 

export const routesData: oneRoute[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        main: (match: match<any>, location: H.Location, history: H.History) => <Home match={match} location={location} history={history} />
    },

    {
        path: '/test/:id',
        exact: false,
        main: (match: match<ITestProps>, location: H.Location, history: H.History) => <Test match={match} location={location} history={history} />
    }
]

export const routes = <Layout>
    {
    routesData.map((route, index) => {
        return <Route exact={route.exact} key={index} path={route.path} component={route.main} />;
    })
}    
</Layout>;
```

And I have an error in Test on link "/test/12".

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

If I comment `this.props.match.params.id`, `JSON.stringify(this.props.match)` shows `"match":{"path":"/test/:id","url":"/test/12","isExact":true,"params":{"id":"12"}}` so there is `params.id`.
How could it be, and how to solve problem to get `this.props.match.params.id`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up here, your component `Test` gets a param called `match` with a **property** called `match` on it that has the actual object that you want (`this.props.match.match.params.id`).

You told your `Route` that the `component` to render is:

```
(match: match<ITestProps>, location: H.Location, history: H.History) => <Test match={match} location={location} history={history} />
```

Components only get called with one argument, which is an object of props.  At runtime, the variable `match` here is not `match<ITestProps>`, it's the whole `RouteComponentProps` object.

Typescript doesn't warn you about this when setting `component={route.main}` because `route.main` is type `any`, so it's assumed to be compatible.

Be more specific in your interface:

```
interface oneRoute {
    path: string;
    exact?: boolean;
    main: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>;
}
```

You could have `main` be function that destructures properties `match`, `location`, and `history` and passes them to the component, but there's really no point given that you aren't changing any props. `main` can just be the component itself.

```
export const routesData: oneRoute[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        main: Home,
    },
    {
        path: '/test/:id',
        exact: false,
        main: Test,
    }
]
```